# Create simple HTML demos based on template with different URL paths

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I would like to obtain on my localhost (somehow dynamically) the following URLs:

```
localhost/demo1/
localhost/demo2/
localhost/demo3/
...
```

and so on (more than 30).

I have an index.php file which I would like to use as a template for each of the above paths.

When I access `localhost/demoX/` I would like to load the `index.php` template only with some few changes inside, based on the `demoX` name.

Can you tell me how to obtain this structure?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP

1) Parse site URL (hint for url `"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) to get variable you need (I think you will use RegEx for that)
2) `$template = require_once('index.php');`
3) Process all variables used in `index.php`
4) `echo $template; exit();`

---

*NOT TESTED PSEUDO CODE*

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part = preg_match("/demo(\d+)/", $url)[0];
$partName = "File name is demo-{$part}";
$template = require_once('index.php');
echo $template;
exit();

[index.php]
<?php
echo $partName;
```